# Set Different Multiplier Value for Different Size Classes in Xcode Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes

I have a `UIImage`. When this `UIImage` appears on an iPhone I want the height of this `UIImage` to be 0.5 of the height of the screen. When this `UIImage` appears on an iPad, I want the hight of the `UIImage` to be 0.3 of the height of the screen.

I have tried using Interface Builder Size Classes to set a different `Multiplier` for `Compact|Regular` and `Regular|Regular`, but when I change the `Multiplier` value, it changes across all Size Classes.

Is there a way to set a different `Multiplier` value for different Size Classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create two equal heights constraints set one with multiplier 0.5, the other with 0.3. Click on the 0.5 constraint, open the size inspector, unclick installed, click the plus next to the installed checkbox, select compact|regular/any. Do the same for the 0.3, but select regular|regular.